# How to get a TA for a thesis

Tags: thesis, advisor, undergraduate

I’m writing an academic paper for a B.Sc.

We only have the professor and a PhD student from another university plus random friends and volunteer collaborators helping us. We were not specifically assigned a TA for our project. I think that it would be much better if we had a PhD student as a TA who could help us instead of only meetings with the professor.

My professor has eight groups in the course and a TA maybe wouldn’t have that many groups. Can I just write to a PhD student in the faculty and ask for help? I was already rejected once when I asked another professor.

Comment: "We were not specifically assigned a TA for our project." - is that the usual thing that happens in your department/at your university/in your university system, that students writing their B.Sc. thesis get assigned a TA?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Not that I know, but I think it would be logical part of Ph D work and also time-efficient so that we can speak with a TA instead of the professor.

Comment: Well, tutoring BSc theses *is* a part of PhD candidate work in some places, but in that case, it's usually the PhD candidates who devise the BSc thesis topic themselves rather than the professor. Thus, I am not sure describing such an apparently rather different situation would be helpful as an answer to this question.

Comment: With that said, didn't an earlier version of this question refer to the BSc *thesis*? Is this about a paper within the BSc now, or about the BSc thesis?

Comment: @DjDac Time efficient for you and maybe the professor, not for the TA. (Speaking as a PhD student who spends way more time taking care of bachelor students than the "TA time" which is actually assigned to supervision of a bachelor student for our groups budget.)

Comment: While I was trying to find out your localisation by checking your profile I realised that it actually includes a link to your bachelor thesis. Which confuses me even more. Have you already finished your thesis? Is this a draft (which I would advise not to publish in this way)?

Comment: @skymningen Yes it is a draft with deadline this week. What is it that you don't agree with?

Comment: I am in no position to agree or disagree, I just would advise (me, as a person, not based on law) not to publish a bachelor thesis draft online. Hearing that, with the deadline being this week... it might be too late for you to search for an additional reader, as it is way too little time to read and comment this for the first time for someone who has probably a lot of other work to do. Which might be the actual reason why they turn you down.

Comment: @skymningen We wanted comments and got very good suggestions. I have restricted the access to only invited collaborators now who already started commenting and making suggestions. We had help from three Ph D students and the professor but I would have liked to have a meeting or two with the Ph D student instead of the professor because the Ph D students are very knowledgable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I work there is actually some part of what you want implemented.
Professors have assigned teaching duties for their group, which usually include supervision of bachelor and master students. 
This means we have to supervise X students per term to meet the requirements for our group (I have no exact idea what happens if we don't, but I think it will end in a reduction of our budget.)

Compared to what we "earn" for teaching a lecture of one hour per week, the assigned points we get for supervision of one bachelor student though are ridiculously low, basically accounting for less than 20 minutes spend per week. Also, if we have more students (which we usually do), we do not get additional budget assigned.

How much time you spend with a bachelor student depends a lot on the stage they are in with their thesis, but also on the needs of the student and the type of project they do. It has always been more than 20 minutes for me. I am not sure, how you would account for this with a TA. Also, they would not necessarily have the in-depth knowledge of a topic that is needed for good supervision.

Quite often, universities offer short courses or even "counseling" hours for the general writing and organizing you work part of a thesis. You might have to look out for that if that is what you need. Sometimes there are even senior students setting up "bring your work and we will all talk about the problems you have" hours for bachelors (or people having trouble with academic writing in general, also before starting their thesis work).
Because re-reading your post, I think you are actually doing your first writing (course report, academic homework, something we would call  "seminar work") and not your thesis.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly there would be many benefits to having a TA assigned to assist with your project, and in a perfect world that would be great.  The main problem is most likely: **money**.

TAs need to be paid, and typically a university allocates assistantships based on the number of courses that need to be taught.  TAs for independent studies are almost certainly not in the budget.

You might argue that the cost would be offset by savings in the professor's time.  Ah, but professors are salaried, and very often they are asked to supervise independent studies on top of their regular teaching and research duties, for no additional pay.  So that savings in time may not translate into any savings in money.

You can certainly ask a graduate student if they would like to help you, just out of the goodness of their heart, but unless your project is exceptionally interesting, I think they'd likely say no.  Grad students have lots of  responsibilities that are directly tied to getting paid and staying on track toward finishing their degrees, and your project isn't one of them.

If there is a grad student with particularly relevant expertise, you could ask to have just a single meeting with them.  Requests like that are more likely to be accepted, when a limited amount of time is involved.  Or, you could offer to pay them by the hour (out of your own pocket), as for private tutoring.

In any of these cases, before requesting any kind of help from a grad student, make sure the professor advising you knows and approves.  They may give you guidelines on how to make sure your work remains your own, and that your consultation isn't considered to be cheating.